# How to solve Duplicate Relationship error while installing a package?

Tags: salesforce1-app

Good day people. Let me state my problem.
I've my own org also one client org. There's some custom fields on client's org for Account object. But, my org doesn't have those custom fields, moreover there are some lookup relationship with these custom field. So, I had to create the custom field manually and set the lookup relationships in my org. That means:

1. I've created same field as my custom's org.
2. Used that field for lookup relationship, same as customer's org.
3. Now created a package to deploy on custom org.

But, while trying to deploy the package, I'm facing duplicate relationship error, as the custom field on Account object is same as mine. I intend to keep this that way without changing my custom field name or anything. Is there any proper solution to this? Thanks in advance.
[image: Error image]

Comment: Is this an unmanaged package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use an [Unlocked Package](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/unlocked-packages-for-customers) in order to avoid this problem. Unmanaged Packages do not allow duplicate fields or relationships, and will abort the installation. The only solution would be to have the relationship renamed. You can also use other tools, such as the metadata API to deploy changes. Unmanaged Packages are most likely the incorrect solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For my better understanding, if I use unlocked Package, the problem will be solved? I don't want to rename it. So, by only using unlocked package will solve the issue (without renaming or any other changes)?

Comment: please reply to my query. Thank you.

Comment: @HasanOnM Correct. Unlocked Packages can overlay non-namespace metadata, but be aware that the field will become part of the package's metadata, if it exists, when you install the package.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: Could you please provide me another information? Which files are added actaully to the unlocked package. All the files are added automatically on the VScode or based on the path on the json file, files are added?

Comment: @HasanOnM All the files in the path in the packageDirectories.